# Bitbucket. Pipelines. bitbucket upload build output from pipeline docker by curl

Tags: curl, bitbucket, bitbucket-api, bitbucket-pipelines

Im trying upload war file to bitbucket downloads from the bitbucket pipeline, my script look like that:

```
    image: maven:3.3.3

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - mvn -B clean install
          - curl -X POST --user "${BB_AUTH_STRING}" "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/someuser/somerepo/downloads" --form files=@"target/some.war"
```

Build is ok, in log i see:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
+ curl -X POST --user "${BB_AUTH_STRING}" "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/someuser/somerepo/downloads" --form files=@"target/some.war"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100 64.2M    0     0  100 64.2M      0   102M --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  102M
```

But the file does not appear in my downloads section (user and repo names is correct). Any ideas? 
What I am wrong?

Comment: Yes I am seeing the same issue as well. 
```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0 13.4M    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
100 13.4M    0     0  100 13.4M      0   9.9M  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  9.9M```

Answer (score 1):

I found the working arguments to curl are these:

```
curl -X POST --user "${BITBUCKET_REPO_OWNER}:${BB_AUTH_STRING}" "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/${BITBUCKET_REPO_OWNER}/${BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG}/downloads/" --form files=@"target/some.war"
```

Specifically, providing a correct user:password combination to curl seems to work.

Using just the app password for authentication does allow the upload to go through but it doesn't really seem to work beyond that.